# Directory.CreateDirectory does not work

Tags: c#, directory, .net

I am creating an application using C# 2010 whose purpose is to copy files that have a specified extension. It uses .NET Framework 3.5 .

I have the following piece of code:

```
    private void GetFiles()
    {
        bool validext;
        foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            //Check if the file has a specified extension
            validext = false;
            foreach (string extension in ext)
                if (HasExtension(filePath, extension))
                {
                    validext = true;
                    break;
                }

            if ((validext && mode == 1) || (!validext && mode == 2))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
                to_copy.Add(filePath);
            }
        }
        totalcount = to_copy.Count;
    }
```

The problem is on this command:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(TrimFile(filePath));
```

It doesn't raise any exception, the directory path it should create is valid and the application runs with administrator privileges. Nevertheless, the directory is not created. Searching the internet didn't give me any answers, so my question is:

Why is `Directory.CreateDirectory(TrimFile(filePath));` not working?

EDIT: I have replaced the FileTrim function with `Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)` .

Comment: Can you post the output of `TrimFile(filePath)` please.

Comment: What is the purpose of TrimFile? Can you show us what the contents of the path string was before and after going through TrimFile? I would guess that that is where your problem lies

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888228/why-is-io-directory-createdirectory-succeeding-when-it-shouldnt

Comment: Example for TrimFile:
Input: C:\Users\VladIulian\Downloads\Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 (x86) - DVD (English)\VSLS.exe
Output: C:\Users\VladIulian\Downloads\Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 (x86) - DVD (English)

Comment: @DavidBrabant, I was aware of that post but Microsoft says the following: Scenario 2: You cannot find the file or the folder that you just created
When you use an application for which virtualization is enabled, you create data files in virtualizable locations of the file system. When you use another application or Windows Explorer to access these newly created files, you cannot find them. For example, if you save a file in a photo editing application in the %programfiles%, %systemroot%, %systemdrive%, or %programdata% folders, you cannot locate this file.

Comment: @DavidBrabant, I use complete paths, so this shouldn't apply. If I am wrong please correct me. Thanks.

Comment: 1. You trying to create directory that already exists. 2. You can use `Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)` instead `TrimFile`.

Comment: @Reniuz, thanks for number 2, I wasn't aware of that. I have replaced it in the code but it still doesn't work. I am not trying to create directory that already exists.

Comment: Here is an example. In first loop iteration lets say you have `filePath = "C:\dir\abc.txt"` later you trimming file name in path and trying to create directory of `"C:\dir\"` but you already have that directory and in that directory exists file.

Comment: @Reniuz, but that should create the directory with the first file. Also, as far as I know, Directory.CreateDirectory does not raise an event if the specified directory already exists.

Comment: YES. you are trying to create directory that already exists. Say your filePath is `C:\Users\blah\VSLS.exe`, as @Reniuz mentioned `Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)` or your supposed `TrimFile()` will return `C:\Users\blah`. So Basically you are calling `Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\blah")`, which means you are trying to create existing directory

Comment: ok add `if(!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)))` before `Directory.CreateDirectory()` and you'll see that you wont enter if statement

Comment: @Reniuz That is surprisingly correct ... Does this have anything to do with this? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927387/EN-US/ If so, how can I fix it / make the directories visible? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets "debug" code

```
private void GetFiles()
{
    //1. Lets say SourcePath = "C:\some\kind\of\directory\"
    foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        //2. Lets say we have file filePath = "C:\some\kind\of\directory\file.txt"

        //.. all validation

        //3. At this point Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\some\kind\of\directory\file.txt")
        //   returns "C:\some\kind\of\directory\"
        //4. Lets create that directory...but wait its already exist and contains some files! 
        //   Why create what already exists?
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
        to_copy.Add(filePath);
    }
}
```

So the truth is that your CreateDirectory call is useless, because you already looping through existing files in directories. Unless you want to create lets say in all directories new sub directory "Temp" then you need to do this:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath), "Temp"));
```

After that you will get `C:\some\kind\of\directory\Temp` directory created.

To copy file to other directory you need to do this:

```
string directoryToCopyFiles = @"C:\My\directory\of\file\copies";
if(!Directory.Exists(directoryToCopyFiles))
   Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryToCopyFiles);

File.Copy(Path.Combine(directoryToCopyFiles, Path.GetFileName(filePath)), filePath);
```

After that directory `C:\My\directory\of\file\copies` will be created if it didn't existed before and file with the same name will be copied there.

Comment: I think I didn't detail the purpose of the program correctly. The error was that I was trying to create the directories I wanted to copy in the source folder, rather than in the destination folder, which was obviously pointless as you pointed out. The solution was to replace the Directory.CreateDirectory with `Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath).Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));`.

Comment: Nevertheless, your comment pointed me in the right direction so it is actually an answer. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I've recently fallen in this as well, and silly me I wasn't concreting the right path, so it was creating the directory I concreted... **inside the `VSProjects/ProjectName/bin/Debug/`** :'D

Before:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(properties.ApiConfigRoute)))
      Directory.CreateDirectory("ConfigFolder");
```

After:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(properties.ApiConfigRoute)))
      Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(properties.ApiConfigRoute));
```

Doh! Hope it helps. Just make sure you're creating it with the **absolute route**.