# C# code not creating directory or saving file

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm making an Outlook plugin which will automatically save messages to a file server when received.  This part of the code simply doesn't do what it's asked to do!

```
//RelevantDirectory[0] is the root folder where I want to save stuff, and sits on a mapped network drive where I have full admin permissions.

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(RelevantDirectory[0] + "\\Email Correspondence\\");
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(RelevantDirectory[0] + "\\Email Correspondence\\Outgoing");

mail.SaveAs(RelevantDirectory[0] + "\\Email Correspondence\\Outgoing\\" + mail.SenderName + " - " + string.Format("text-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}", mail.ReceivedTime) + ".msg");
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(System.IO.File.Exists(RelevantDirectory[0] + "\\Email Correspondence\\Outgoing\\" + mail.SenderName + " - " + string.Format("text-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}", mail.ReceivedTime) + ".msg").ToString()); //returns True!
```

The MessageBox returns True, yet the file isn't actually there!  The CreateDirectory code also doesn't create the directory - and I'm sure that the filepath in the program is correct.  I understand from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888228/why-is-io-directory-createdirectory-succeeding-when-it-shouldnt) that this could have something to do with filesystem virtualisation.  If so, how do I get around the problem?

One more point is that if I point mail.SaveAs to the Desktop folder, it saves it.

**EDIT** For some bizarre reason, using `Path.Combine()` worked.  Credit to Sinatr.  Thanks for your hints everyone.

Comment: Try to use `Path.Combine` when creating pathes.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? What is the value of `RelevantDirectory[0]`?

Comment: And you don't need to create every folder, just use `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(RelevantDirectory[0] + "\\Email Correspondence\\Outgoing");` will create you required folder structure.

Comment: RelevantDirectory[0] is the correct string.  It points to J:\London\LO-E1-005 as expected.

Comment: @Bolu, I'm aware of that.  I just split the code up as a debugging step.

Comment: @Sinatr, I will try Path.Combine and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Are you sure `mail.SaveAs()`-method isn't the problem?

Comment: Visual Studio Professional 2013, Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: @JoriO Yes, since System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory doesn't create the directory either.

Comment: I would try saving the message straight to `RelevantDirectory[0]`. The drive letter J suggest that it isn't on the local drive, and that way I'd be sure that my program is able to write files there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line:

```
string.Format("text-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}", mail.ReceivedTime)
```

When converted to string it becomes somthing like : 1/1/2014 12:35:35 PM
when creating files a '/' and ':' are illegal characters , so for the minimal amount change I suggest you append a couple Replace functions at the end of your string.Format like this:

```
string.Format("text-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}", mail.ReceivedTime).Replace('/','-').Replace(':',' ')
```

Comment: I think you will find that this is not right. The output format specified is clearly already using '-' character as separators not '/'. Try executing the statement yourself with the current date time (DateTime.Now) as the input. You should get something like 'text-2014-10-11_12-06-55-AM'